# Convergence of $2x^{2n-1}(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate the limit

$\lim_{n\to +\infty} 2x^{2n-1}(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$

and to find out if the sequence of function converges uniformly.

I foud that the limit is $0$ if $|x|<1$ and $\pm\infty$ if $|x|>1$, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Then I have to study if $f_n (x) = 2x^{2n-1}(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$ converges uniformly. I tried with some estimations, but I can't find a $sup$ that converges if $n\to + \infty$

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the functions are odd, we can first assume $x \geq 0$.

$$\frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}} = \frac{2x^{2n}\frac{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{1}{n}}{x}}{1+x^{2n}} = \frac{2x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}\left(x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$

If $x > 1$ then $\frac{1}{x^n} \le x^n$:
$$x = \sqrt[n]{x^n} \le \left(x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (2x^n)^\frac{1}{n} = \sqrt[n]{2}\cdot x\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x$$

$$\frac{2x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x^{2n}} + 1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 2$$

So:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = 2x$$

If $x = 1$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = 1$$

If $x < 1$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2x^{2n-1} = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n} = 1$. Thus:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = 0$$

We can conclude:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 1$} \\
1,  & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
2x,  & \text{if $x > 1$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Expanding the domain to $\mathbb{R}$, we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}} = \begin{cases}
2x,  & \text{if $x < -1$} \\
-1,  & \text{if $x = -1$} \\
0,  & \text{if $|x| < 1$} \\
1,  & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
2x,  & \text{if $x > 1$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Functions $x \mapsto \frac{2x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^{2n})^\frac{n-1}{n}}$ are continuous for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since the limit function is not continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform.

**Edit:**

Let's check if the convergence is uniform in $[0,a]$ for $a < 1$:

Let $f_n(x) = 2x^{2n-1}(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$. The derivative is:

$$f_n'(x) = -4(n-1)x^{4n-2}(1+x^{2n})^{\left(-1+\frac{1-n}{n}\right)} + 2(2n-1)x^{2n-2}(1+x^{2n})^\frac{1-n}{n}$$

Rearranging $f'_n(x) = 0$ gives:

$$\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2n-1}{n-1}\implies x^{2n}=1-2n < 0$$

Thus, $f_n$ has no stationary points. This implies that the supremum on $[0,a]$ is $|f(a)| = 2a^{2n-1}(1+a^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$.

$$\|f_n - 0\|_{\infty,[0,a]} = \|f_n\|_{\infty,[0,a]} = 2a^{2n-1}(1+a^{2n})^{\frac{1-n}{n}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Thus, $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ uniformly on $[0,a]$.

Comment: The limit is $2x$ if $x < -1$. And what if I want to study the uniform convergence in intervals like $[0, a]$ with $a < 1$ and $[b,\infty)$ with $b >1$? The derivative is hard to study and I cannot find any useful estimation

Comment: @brt22 I just calculated the derivative, it seems to converge uniformly on $[0,a]$. I have included it in my answer.

Comment: Seems ok, thank you. What about $[b,\infty)$ with $b>1$? Can we find a supremum that converges?

Comment: @brt22 The question is whether $\|f_n - 2x\|_{\infty, [b, +\infty)}$ converges to $0$, as $2x$ is the only candidate for uniform convergence. I haven't been able to get anything useful on that.